# Frustrum culling without per-mesh positions

Tags: opengl, c++, assimp, frustum-culling, sponza

I am trying to implement frustrum culling in a C++ renderer im writing but I feel like I hit a brick wall. 
The plan is to load the Sponza level and per mesh create a collision box using Bullet physics library, which also holds the mesh translation, scale and rotation, then get the camera planes and check if the collision box falls inside the planes. I'm loading the Sponza level using the Assimp library, it loads fine and displays correctly but every node's transformation is at 0,0,0  which leads me to believe all the vertices are pre-translated already (even without optimization flags). I checked it out in Blender and even there the translation gizmo is at 0,0,0 for every mesh. I tried a couple different sponza files, FBX too but they all lack per mesh positions. Should I just give up on this? Are there other ways to perform frustrum culling?

Comment: Why would this matter? The AABB of an object at (0, 0, 0) with vertices at (5, 1, 4) & (3, 7, 6) is the same as the AABB of an object at (4, 4, 5) with vertices at (1, -3, -1) & (-1, 3, 1). The object's origin does not factor into the frustum culling decision making at all. Only the bounds of the transformed vertices matter, and those are the same whether the object's origin is close to its geometric center or arbitrarily far away.

Comment: So I should try to make a bullet collision shape out of the per mesh vertex data?

Comment: Have you tried that and run into any specific problem we can help you solve?

Comment: Not yet but you did point me in the right direction, I misunderstood the theory behind frustrum culling. Thanks!

Comment: @nicovanBentum Just to elaborate, the approach I use is to calculate the optimised bounding box of the untranslated model, then use your Transform matrix on a copy of those points.  You test the 8 points against the Frustum test, if the 8 points lay outside any of those planes then it's safe to cull.   Just summing up this thread.  GL.